# How can I store image in phpmyadmin database?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I can't store image in phpmyadmin database.

In my table
Create table login(
photo longblob not null );

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

actually I recommend you to save only the file name in the database...

First you save the file in a folder there, take the name of it and save it in the bank... follow my solution.

**1- Create a folder on your server/hosting. (example: upload)**

**No HTML**

```
<form action="salve.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form- 
data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="">
    <button type="submit">SaveFile</button>
</form>
```

**salve.php**

```
 if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['midia']['tmp_name'])) {


  $nome_original = $_FILES['midia']['name'];
  $pasta = "upload/"; //pach an file

  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['midia']['tmp_name'], $pasta . 
  $nome_original)) {

    ##############################
    ##//Save this name in the bank
    ########################
    $nome_original;



   } else {
    echo "Erros ao salv Mídia:" . $_FILES["midia"]["error"];
   }
 }
```

Espero que ajude